# The Sheaf of Regular Functions on an Affine Algebraic Set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, affine-varieties

So, I'm trying to show that the ring of regular functions on an affine algebraic set forms a sheaf. I have no problem showing that they form a presheaf, that much is clear, but the two additional things you have to prove I find particularly annoying. To quote Hartshorne, p. 61:

> (4) if $U$ is an open set, if $\{ V_i \}$ is an open covering of $U$, and if we have elements $s_i \in \mathcal{F}(V_i)$ for each $i$ with the property that for each $i,j$, $s_i |_{V_i \cap V_j} = s_j |_{V_i \cap V_j}$, then there is an element $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $s|_{V_i} = s_i$.

Fair enough I figure, only to then ask the question, what if the overlap between the different $V_i$ are always the empty set? After all, is there anything compelling $U$ to not be disjoint?

Consider then the following schematic:

[[image: The open set <span class=]$U \subset X$ has an open covering of $\{ V_1 , V_2, V_3 \}$.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXGTK.png)

Since $V_i \cap V_j = \varnothing$ for all $i,j$, it trivially follows that $\mathcal{F}(V_i \cap V_j) = \{ 0 \}$ and so $s_i |_{V_i \cap V_j} = s_j |_{V_i \cap V_j} = 0$ **for all** $s_i \in V_i, s_j \in V_j$. But that then would imply that the restriction morphisms $\rho_{UV_i}$ must all **necessarily** be surjective. And that just strikes me as odd and deeply suspicious.

What, and where, am I doing something that must be terribly wrong?

Look forward to your responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing suspicious about the restriction maps being surjective. In fact, a sheaf with this property has a special name: [flasque sheaf](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09SV).

As for the open cover having trivial intersections, the sheaf condition becomes vacuously true as you point out. Note that if the underlying topological space is irreducible, then open subsets are always dense, and therefore intersections of nontrivial open subsets aren't empty.

Comment: Does it really become vacuously true? Because I don't see how there necessarily must exist $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $s|_{V_i} = s_i$ for all $V_i$. Indeed, it would appear that if $U$ is irreducible and the intersections are trivial, that then would imply that for arbitrary $a \in \mathcal{F}(V_1), b \in \mathcal{F}(V_2) , c \in \mathcal{F}(V_3)$ there would necessarily have to exist some $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ such that $s|_{V_1} = a$,  $s|_{V_2} = b$, and  $s|_{V_3} = c$. Am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Define $s = a$ on $V_1$, $s = b$ on $V_2$, and so on. Since regularity is a local property, we end up with a regular function.

Comment: Wait, you can do that? For instance, let $X = \mathbb{C}$ and let $U=V_1 \cup V_2$, with $V_1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | -2< \Re(z)<-1 \}$ and $V_2 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | 1< \Re(z)<2 \}$. Let then $a \in \mathcal{F} (V_1)$ be $a(x) = x^2+1$ and $b \in \mathcal{F} (V_2)$ be $b(x) = x+43$. How do I then find a ratio of polynomials $s = \frac{f}{g}$ that on $V_1$ looks like $a(x)$ and on $V_2$ looks like $b(x)$ but that can still be written as $s$ everywhere on $U$?

Comment: For a point $P \in V_1$, you only need to find a open neighborhood of $P$ such that $s$ can be written as a ratio of polynomials. It doesn't have to apply globally.

Comment: Huh! I was under the impression that the definition of regularity of a function $f$ over an open subset $U$ was such that $f$ could be written as a ratio of polynomials globally on $U$. I take this from that there is a bijection between elements of a coordinate ring $A(X)$ and functions that can globally be written as fractions of polynomials everywhere on $X$.

Comment: Ah! Now I get it! Took me a little while to find all the stuff I needed. On a Zariski closed set (that is, an algebraic set), a regular function (defined locally) can always be globally described as the restriction of a polynomial. On an open set, such as this, that is not the case! **Everything checks out!**